# How to read multiple numbers from a file

Tags: c++

I want to print out the last 10 numbers in my file, but when i try and print it out, my program prints out the last number inputted 10 times. How do i fix this so it inputs the last 10 numbers instead of just the last number?

```
else if (option == 2)
    {
        writefile.open("highscores.txt");
        cout << "You have selected '2.' Here are the current highscores" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10 && !writefile.eof(); i++) 
        {
            writefile >> x;
            cout << x << endl;
        }
```

Here is the input for the program.

```
if (option == 1)
    {
        myfile.open("highscores.txt");
        writefile.open("highscores.txt");
        myfile << "Top Ten Highscores.\n";

        cout << "You have chosen '1.' Please enter 10 scores!" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            cin >> x;
            myfile << x << "\n";
        }

        cout << "Your number has been entered!" << endl;
        myfile.close();
        writefile.close();
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: Your program prints the first ten numbers, doesn't it?

Comment: `!writefile.eof()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: you should rethink your algorithm: read 10 lines, then for every remaining line, discard the top one, move all the others, and add the new one. You can use a queue for that.

Comment: Did you check your file? Perhaps the same # is in there 9 or 10 times.

Comment: The program asks the user to input the 10 numbers, and no the file doesn't have 9 or 10 of the same numbers.

Comment: I still think the bug is in the input.

Comment: The name "writefile" is a bit peculiar for a file that you're reading from.

Comment: My crystal ball thinks that the file is still open after you wrote to it, and that `x` is the same variable that you used for writing.

Comment: Why are you opening the same file 2 times for writing? Also in both reading and writing you should probably make the file variable local to the scope that you need it.

Comment: Give up the habit of reusing variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your txt file contains 11 line, you first need to read string part that you added in option 1.

```
myfile << "Top Ten Highscores.\n";
```

For read this part, you can simlply use `getline(myfile, line)` and `line` should be string. Then you can read numbers from txt file.